# Room with non-final Entity

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room for DB operations in my Android app. Strangely, Room throws an error

`Error:Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.`

whenever I make my entity non-final (or `open` in Kotlin).

If I remove `open`, it works fine. I know for sure that it is not mendatory to keep entities non-final in Room as it works in my other project. I have no idea whats happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

This works

```
@Entity
public final class BaseRow {
```

This does not

```
@Entity
public class BaseRow {
```